# Django unique model fields validation in form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model with a few unique fields and I'm writing a form for it. I found some reference to the `[validate_unique][1]` method that should check for uniqueness on fields when you call it but my form `.is_valid()` always returns `True`.

My testcase:

```
class ServerFormTest( TestCase ):
    def setUp( self ):
        self.server = Server.objects.create( host = "127.0.0.1", name = "localhost" )

    def test_unique_name(self):
        form = ServerForm({
            'name': 'localhost',
            'host': '127.0.0.1'
        })

        self.assertFalse( form.is_valid( ) )
```

and my form:

```
class ServerForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = ('name', 'host')

    def clean( self ):
        self.validate_unique()
        return self.cleaned_data
```

server model:

```
class Server( models.Model ):
    host = models.GenericIPAddressField( blank = False, null = False, unique = True )
    name = models.CharField( blank = False, null = False, unique = True, max_length = 55 )
```

Comment: Can you post your `Server` model as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[validate_unique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) is a `Model` method.

Running the superclass `clean` method should take care of model uniqueness checks given a `ModelForm`.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()
        # additional cleaning here
        return cleaned_data
```

There is a [warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method) on the django docs specifically about overriding clean on `ModelForm`s, which automatically does several model validation steps.

Comment: While you're editing, you have an indentation glitch on the last line in the code block ^^

Comment: @spectras caught in the act!

Answer (score 4):

simple way to achieve uniqueness to a field, just use "unique=True" in the model field. Example:

```
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=_('Email'), max_length=255, unique=True)

phone = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Phone Number'), max_length=14, unique=True)
```

But if you really want to achieve this through form, or situation demands it, for example, in the above code section, here phone number is a character field. uniqueness is difficult to achieve here because for the system 0171-xxxxxxx and 0171xxxxxxx are different numbers but actually they are same. It can be easily validated through form's clean_phone method. Here the digit is parsed from the string(character field) before checking uniqueness.

```
    def clean_phone(self):
        phone = self.cleaned_data.get("phone")
        # parse digits from the string
        digit_list = re.findall("\d+", phone)
        phone = ''.join(digit_list)
        
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(phone=phone).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("phone number is already exists")
        return phone
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve it by adding `validate_unique()` to `save()`

```
class Server( models.Model ):
    host = models.GenericIPAddressField( blank = False, null = False, unique = True )
    name = models.CharField( blank = False, null = False, unique = True, max_length = 55 )

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.validate_unique()
        super(Server,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works for me. I don't know about you.