# Validation for unique in form

Tags: python, django

I have model and form like this

```
class Article(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False,unique=True)

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Article
    key = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

This `key` is unique in table, so I want to validate in form too.

If I put the existing key, it comes to the

`1062, "Duplicate entry 'inquiry' for key` error in yellow screen

However it also doesn't work,

```
forms.CharField(required=True,unique=True)
```

How can I make this validation?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052975/django-models-avoid-duplicates) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you but it's not. I set up for model already, I need validator for form html

Comment: Possibly duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150929/django-unique-model-fields-validation-in-form